# How to automate everyday mail task?

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

I want to automate one of my everyday tasks. The scenario is like this:

I have to draft a mail like this in Microsoft Outlook.

> Hi `XXX`,
>
> Please consider the code `ZZZ` for the approval.

There is a specific `XXX` value for every `ZZZ`. These values are
 stored in microsoft excel in different coloumns.

Is there any way so that I can generate mails in this fixed format for number of times?
Outlook properties or by script method?

Comment: Try mail merge. If that's too limited, learn to program and come back when you have a specific programming question.

Comment: Please show us the code you tried to prepare: this is NOT a [Freecode.com](http://freecode.com/), and community is glad to HELP you, but won't do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but i think i am completely misunderstood.I don't want you guys to write code for me. I just want a guidance.I just want to know whether is this possible? if yes then how ?If you guys suggest me something i will do further digging into it...

Answer (score 0):

I use CDO to send my emails from Excel VBA.  [Check out this article](http://www.rondebruin.nl/cdo.htm) to get you started.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you, it had helped me a lot: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail1.htm

There are few simple examples too.